# How can one insert a video in an Office 365 PowerPoint presentation without having to host the video on some website outside Office 365 PowerPoint?

Tags: video, office-365

I want to insert a video in an Office 365 PowerPoint presentation without having to host the video on some website outside Office 365 PowerPoint. I could only find a way to add an online video to my slides:

[image]

How can one insert a video in an Office 365 PowerPoint presentation without having to host the video on some website outside Office 365 PowerPoint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to insert a video in an Office 365 PowerPoint presentation without having to host the video on some website outside Office 365 PowerPoint, [according to](https://redd.it/owun45) Reddit user  [SteveRindsberg](https://www.reddit.com/user/SteveRindsberg):

> You're using the web version of PowerPoint; it has a number of limitations that the desktop version doesn't have; this is one.
>
> If you [insert a video into your presentation using the desktop version](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-and-play-a-video-file-from-your-computer-f3fcbd3e-5f86-4320-8aea-31bff480ed02?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) (PC or Mac), the video will be embedded in your PPT file; no need to host it elsewhere.